# Include value from one column in another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to tweak a google sheets script that sends messages with Twillio. What I want to do is include data from one column into another as a variable. For instance, one column has company name the other has the text message body. I want to be able to type something in the message that will automatically fill in the Company name when called.

"Hi! Congratulations on getting your license for "companyName". Give us a call to get set up.

translates to

Hi! Congratulations on getting your license for ABC Company. Give us a call to get set up. when it is sent.

So There is a column for Company Name and One for Message Body. The var functions are already included that call the different columns.

Right now I'm having to hard code it into the script like this, but I want to be able to script this to where text is not hard coded.

```
function sendSms(customerPhoneNumber, companyName, messageBody)     {
 var twilioAccountSID = userProperties.getProperty('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID');
 var twilioAuthToken = userProperties.getProperty('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN');
 var twilioPhoneNumber = userProperties.getProperty('TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER');
 var twilioUrl = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + twilioAccountSID + '/Messages.json';
 var authenticationString = twilioAccountSID + ':' + twilioAuthToken;
 try {
   UrlFetchApp.fetch(twilioUrl, {
 method: 'post',
 headers: {
   Authorization: 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(authenticationString)
 },
 payload: {
   To: "+" + customerPhoneNumber.toString(),
   Body: "Hi! Congratulations on getting your license for " + companyName + ", " + messageBody,
   From: twilioPhoneNumber,  // Your Twilio phone number
 },
   });
   return 'sent: ' + new Date();
 } catch (err) {
   return 'error: ' + err;
 }
};
```

The original technique used to set this up is here: https://www.twilio.com/blog/send-sms-google-sheets-twilio

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine your Spreadsheet from `What I want to do is include data from one column into another as a variable. For instance, one column has company name the other has the text message body. I want to be able to type something in the message that will automatically fill in the Company name when called.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet as an image?

Comment: Is this your complete script? If not, can you include how you're retrieving your `customerPhoneNumber, companyName, messageBody` parameters for this function?